# Windows RDP disconnects before connection is established in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop

I've installed xrdp in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server edition with xfce but I'm not able to login through windows computer with default RDP. It shows as connected/loaded and the dialogue box closes and RDP stops automatically.

Here is the sesman log data that might help.

```
starting sesman in foregroud...
[20170303-01:07:14] [CORE ] starting sesman with pid 10454
[20170303-01:07:14] [INFO ] listening...
[20170303-01:07:30] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 7 started successfully
[20170303-01:07:30] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username biku, ip 192.168.100.18:56726 - socket: 7
[20170303-01:07:30] [INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
03/03/17 01:07:30 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
03/03/17 01:07:30 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
03/03/17 01:07:30 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
03/03/17 01:07:30 All Rights Reserved.
03/03/17 01:07:30 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
03/03/17 01:07:30 Desktop name 'x11' (ubuntu:10)
03/03/17 01:07:30 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
03/03/17 01:07:30 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5910
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/Speedo/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
[20170303-01:07:30] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sessvc - xpid=10460 - wmpid=10459
xrdp-sessvc: waiting for X (pid 10460) and WM (pid 10459)
xrdp-chansrv [2433766571]: main: app started pid 10473(0x000028e9)
xrdp-chansrv [2433766571]: main: DISPLAY env var set to :10.0
xrdp-chansrv [2433766571]: main: using DISPLAY 10
xrdp-chansrv [2433766571]: channel_thread_loop: thread start

03/03/17 01:07:31 Got connection from client 127.0.0.1
03/03/17 01:07:31 Using protocol version 3.3
03/03/17 01:07:31 Full-control authentication passed by 127.0.0.1
03/03/17 01:07:32 Pixel format for client 127.0.0.1:
03/03/17 01:07:32   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
03/03/17 01:07:32   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
03/03/17 01:07:32   no translation needed
03/03/17 01:07:32 Using raw encoding for client 127.0.0.1
03/03/17 01:07:32 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 127.0.0.1
03/03/17 01:07:32 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
xrdp-chansrv [2433767997]: send_init_response_message:
xrdp-chansrv [2433768016]: clipboard_init: no xfixes
xrdp-chansrv [2433768016]: xrdp-chansrv: clipboard_init: error on exit
xrdp-sessvc: WM is dead (waitpid said 10459, errno is 0) exiting...
xrdp-sessvc: stopping channel server
xrdp-chansrv [2433771739]: term_signal_handler: got signal 15
xrdp-chansrv [2433771744]: channel_thread_loop: g_term_event set
xrdp-chansrv [2433771744]: channel_thread_loop: thread stop
xrdp-chansrv [2433771745]: main: app exiting pid 10473(0x000028e9)
xrdp-sessvc: stopping X server
xrdp-sessvc: clean exit
[20170303-01:07:36] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username biku, display :10.0, session_pid 10458, ip 192.168.100.18:56726 - socket: 7
^C[20170303-01:07:47] [INFO ] shutting down sesman 1
[20170303-01:07:47] [CORE ] shutting down log subsystem...
]0;root@ubuntu: /usr/sbinroot@ubuntu:/usr/sbin# exit
exit
```

I'm not sure where the problem lies. Any help is appreciated and I'm new in linux/CLI world. If it helps this server is upgraded from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 & 16.04 LTS.

Comment: What windows version is on client computer? Try in RDP options on client side relax security settings, it probably attempting connection with modern Microsoft's changes

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 to connect the xrdp server.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen people reported this happened because user session is open in X window and proposed to logout before using xrdp.

Answer (score 1):

I  also struggled with this issue for a couple of days. I got this sorted out by adding following 2 lines in `xrdp.ini`:

```
autorun=Xorg

max_bpp=16
```

and than in RDP session selected `xorg` instead of `xvnc`; the connection worked fine.

Comment: it didn't help me...